# SBT Builds with Bamboo

Tags: sbt, bamboo

I was wondering if anyone could recommend best practise for SBT builds using Bamboo. I see that is a [Bamboo plugin for SBT](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.sbt/server/overview) however it is a) unsupported and b) isn't compatible with later versions of Bamboo.  This combination would almost certainly be a blocker for us as using it could lead to a position where we couldn't take a Bamboo update (potentially fixing a security issue) because it would break all of our SBT builds.

Presumably you can just set up Bamboo to build SBT projects as a script task but I'm a bit worried about the experience here as it's not clear to me how things like failing tests and code coverage will be represented.

Is it possible to have a reasonably slick SBT and Bamboo setup without using the plugin or is Bamboo not a suitable CI system to use with SBT?

Answer (score 0):

We do heavily rely on bamboo in our sbt workflows. The plugin works fine but the only benefit over a short inline script is the parsing of tests which is also available as another task.
We love having some portable build scripts in the projects which can be also used by bamboo.

So here is the starter guide:

- have a good portable build script in your project (presumably bash script)
- call this script in an inline script in bamboo (so you can do some other stuff as well, e.g. checkout submodules, choosing docker host, ...)